# How does land demolition work in ArcheAge?

Tags: arche-age

I wanted to know precisely how land demolition works in ArcheAge (EU/NA version, published by Trion), in particular for the unfinished construction yard.

When someone puts on land a house design, you have to pay taxes for deposit and bring there constrution materials. If you don't do anything, after how much time the land return free? I read the sign on the contruction yard itself that tells "protected until...", what does it mean? That the land will return free at expiration of that time, or maybe after that another week starts for the final countdown?

Thanks for any replay/information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a building is untargetable. But when you select the "demolish" option it becomes targetable, you get an mail with the building design and the taxes you paid once you installed your building and everyone can attack the building. Once destroyed, a few seconds later the building disappears and you can put another building in the terrain.

When you don't pay the taxes (one week after you placed the building) it enters in a "overdue" state and you have to pay not paid taxes and the taxes for the new week at once. If another week passes, then is when it becomes unprotected. And I'm not so sure, but my bet is that then acts exactly like the demolish option.

Comment: Buildings are targetable, but cannot be attacked unless they are in the process of being demolished.